# new Color C# (in Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, renderer

```
double red = loc[1] * 25.5;
newBlock.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color((float)red, 0, 0);
```

When I apply this new Color to a variety of cubes in Unity, and loc[1] is a number between 0 and 10, all of the cubes are white, rather than varying shades of red. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color uses value between 0 and 1.

You need to normalize the given values.

```
 new Color(255f/255f, 100f/255f, 0f/255f);
```